# Replace manifest during compilation

Tags: delphi, toolsapi

I want to create IDE extension which allows me to edit Windows manifest directly in Delphi IDE. Is there a way to delete build in manifest and add my own resource without {$R} directive? All my tryings with IOTAProjectResource were failed. I even could not get this interface from IOTAProject. I use Delphi XE3.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no interface to edit the IDE-created manifest. You will likely have to configure the project to use a user-defined external manifest file, then you can edit that file as needed.

Comment: The IDE already allows you to specify your own manifest resource. Why do you feel the need for anything more?

Comment: Yes, it allows. But I must use external tool for manifest creation. I want to create an extension which will support all field of specification (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And it is better if some of them (assemblyIdentity name, description) will be filled automatically from VersionInfo. Another reason - I just want to improve my skills in IDE extensions development :)

Comment: You should really include what did you try, so other users can confirm if there is a common problem.

Comment: Well, it is better to create the version resource yourself and not let the IDE (mis)manage it. Likewise the manifest resource. I do all the myself with my own tooling. But an IDE plugin is not what you need. Not least because I don't always build from the IDE. If you want to do build automation the IDE plugin is categorically the wrong plce for it. You need a build action. Make a build action the creates custom manifest resource and version resource.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will think about your suggestion.